# Windows bash NGINX not completing successful PHP-FPM action

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is a very weird problem...

OS: Windows 10
Env : Ubuntu Bash
Nginx : nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
PHP : PHP 7.2.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

When I do a test directly to PHP-FPM from the CLI, the response is just fine.

like...

> SCRIPT_NAME=/status SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status REQUEST_METHOD=GET
> cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock

to connect to this status system https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/fpm-status-page/

On Nginx startup, it gives these errors in the log

> 2018/06/24 15:08:45 [alert] 6772#6772: *2 open socket #15 left in connection 4
>
> 2018/06/24 15:08:45 [alert] 6772#6772: aborting`

But if I connect to `http://127.0.0.1/status` to test it ( or any local url )... the request hangs until it 502's. with these headers only:

> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Date: Sun, 24 Jun 2018 22:17:13 GMT
> Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked

and this error shows in the nginx log

> 2018/06/24 15:09:48 [error] 6834#6834: *1 upstream timed out (110:
> Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1,
> server: _, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"

But if I kill the PHP-FPM service while it is hanging, then the response shows in the browser perfectly. Just like it does from a direct CLI request.

The rest of the nginx config is default settings. I'm using sock for the fpm, not ip:port. The ip:port setup won't even work with a whole slew of other problems.

So clearly FPM is running properly... but for some reason Nginx specifically isn't able to determine when the response has finished sending and Nginx just hangs on waiting for it to be considered finished, which never happens.. so the page faults. I've been scouring every semi similar solution I can find online and nothing seems to be my same issue; nor do their methods work for me.

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding the following to the http block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf :

```
fastcgi_buffering off;
```

Comment: what if I need buffering to be on? Is there any other workarounds?